# How to document return value of function that calls another function

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Given the following example:

```
/**
 * An outer function
 * @param {number} age - The age to pass to outerFunction
 * @returns {#What goes here?#}
 */
function outerFunction(age){
    return addTen(age)
}

/**
 * Adds 10 to the age
 * @param {number} age - The age to add 10 to
 * @returns {number} - The age + 10
 */
function addTen(age){
    return 10 + age
}
```

the `outerFunction` returns another function's result.

I thought of several ways to document this:

- `@returns {number}` - We know that `addTen` returns a number, but what if this changes? We will have to update both (or each time it is returned, which could be a lot), which isn't maintainable.
- `@returns {function}` - I am not sure if this is available in JsDoc. I couldn't find it anywhere. This also doesn't feel like it gives much information.
- `@returns {any}` or - `@returns {*}` - This isn't particularly helpful to anyone reading the doc.

None of these feel correct to me for the reasons stated.

I guess I want something like

```
@returns {addTen.return}
```

So that I am essentially saying "`outerFunction` returns whatever type `addTen` does".

*Note*: these are in the same place in this example, but could be contained in multiple files, so using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012043/how-to-document-a-function-returned-by-a-function-using-jsdoc) doesn't work, unless it's possible to do this across multiple files.

How do we write JsDoc comments to document that the function returns another function?

Does something similar to my suggestion exist?

Comment: *"the `outerFunction` returns another function"* No, it doesn't. It returns the *result* of *calling* another function, which is something else entirely. From the remainder of the question I think you know that, so it's not an answer, but...

Comment: Ah, good point! My question still stands, in a slightly different format though... I will edit it. I would still like to know how to correctly document this.

Comment: *"We know that `addTen` returns a number, but what if this changes? We will have to update both (or multiple), which isn't maintainable."* Well, `outerFunction` is tightly bound to `addTen`, so any change to `addTen` will indeed affect `outerFunction`, which has knock-on effects -- to the documentation, but more importantly to its functionality.

Comment: So, you're saying that when I change the way that `addTen` works, I also have to change each time anything returns it? I guess I want the documentation for `outerFunction` to reference `addTen`.

Comment: Only if you want `outerFunction`'s public contract to be tied to `addTen`, rather than just its implementation.

Comment: What *should* `outerFunction` return? What's its contract? Imagine you replace the entire innards of `outerFunction` with something completely different, you *refactor* its implementation – presumably the return value should still be the same, because it's specified in its signature/API contract what it's supposed to return, no...?!

Comment: @deceze I think I understand. `outerFunction` should be the same return type because whatever calls `outerFunction` is expecting that return type. In this case, a number. So it's okay for `outerFunction` to have `@return {number}`. I think this answers the question. if you want to turn it into an answer I can accept it.

Comment: The unit test for that function answers the question. Have you written one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The caller of `outerFunction` will have certain expectations of what that function accepts as arguments and what it will return. The caller of `outerFunction` does not care what `outerFunction` does, only that its interface works as described. The caller of `outerFunction` does not know or care nor should they care that some function called `addTen` is involved in anything `outerFunction` does. In fact, someday you may rewrite the entire implementation of `outerFunction` to not call `addTen` anymore, but keep it behaving exactly the same way.

Treat every function individually as a black box. You're describing the interface of `outerFunction`, so describe what it does/is supposed to do. Don't describe it in terms of some other function which may or may not be related. If `outerFunction` is expected to return a number, describe it as such. If `addTen` also happens to return a number, well, what a coincidence.

I understand the impetus to want to implicitly tie the return value of one function to that of another, because that's how it's actually implemented, and you know... DRY and all... But in this case that's counter productive. It doesn't matter that you "repeat" the "same information" about the return type on two different functions; because you're not describing a connected thing. Both functions are independent black boxes with their own specific signature; that their implementation happens to be coupled is irrelevant for that, and may in fact change tomorrow. What is important is that the signature stays as described.

In fact, if `addTen` did change its return type (and implicitly so did `outerFunction`), that would be a big deal anyway that's not just going to blow over by implicitly updating some documentation. By changing the return type of *any* function, you're breaking a previously established contract, which will have a cascade of effects to every user of that function. Implicitly and automatically updating the return type of `outerFunction` is the least of your worries in such a scenario, as you might have to rewrite large swaths of code to conform to the new contract.

Comment: I know this is old, but I think it's a bit situational. Sometimes, you're writing a higher-order function, or a facade, or an adapter that might necessarily want to return the exact same type as another function. If you're writing a mock, for example, you might want to guarantee that you're returning the same type as the function you're mocking so that if your mock returns a string but the original gets changed to a number, the whole thing should blow up at build time.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I just encountered a similar issue recently. I'm leaving my solution for anyone who has this issue to refer to. But please note that all I needed were some type hints in VS Code. If you are using some docgen tools, or you can only use the official jsdoc syntax then this answer is probably not for you.

So in this example, if all you need are some type hints in editors, you don't need to add any return type to the `outerFunction`:

```js
/**
 * An outer function
 * @param {number} age - The age to pass to outerFunction
 */
function outerFunction(age){
  return addTen(age)
}
```

The above code will work automatically (if `addTen` is properly typed). But if you really need to reference the return type of `addTen`, for example:

```js
// The param `addedAge` is definitely something returned by `addTen`
function outerFunction(addedAge) {
  return addedAge + addTen(10) // becomes `any`
}
```

In this example if `addedAge` is a number, `outerFunction` returns a number; if `addedAge` is a string, then it returns a string as well. In this case you can:

```js
/**
 * @param {ReturnType<addTen>} addedAge
 * @returns {ReturnType<addTen>}
 */
function outerFunction(addedAge) {
  return addedAge + addTen(10)
}
```

Again, this is not the official jsdoc syntax, but for editors like VS Code, the typing system is built on top of TypeScript so you can use TypeScript features directly.

Besides, you can even import a type (or function) in jsdoc:

```js
/**
 * @param {ReturnType<import('../fn').addTen>} addedAge
 */
function outerFunction(addedAge) {
  return addedAge + addTen(10)
}
```

For anyone who wants some types but can't migrate to TypeScript yet, I hope this will help.