# How to document a function returned by a function using JSDoc without modifying the latter one?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc3

This question is very similar to [another one on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30012043/how-to-document-a-function-returned-by-a-function-using-jsdoc), except that there is one more restriction: I cannot modify the function that creates new functions.

Let's say we have an object named `someObject` with a method called `addMethod` that can be used to create new methods for this object like this:

```
someObject.addMethod( "methodName", function () {
    // Do some stuff here
} );
```

I want to document `someObject` using jsDoc, but I am not allowed to modify it except through the use of its addMethod function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the only way I found was not to use an anonymous function and to use the @memberof jsDoc tag like this:

```
someObject.addMethod("publicName", myPublicMethod);

/**
 * @function
 * @memberof SimpleObject#
 * @desc
 * The description of myPublicMethod.
 *
 * @returns true if  can capture the display.
 */
function myPublicMethod() {

};
```

I thought I would have to use @memberof! (the forced form of @memberof; notice the exclamation mark), but it was not necessary. It works even if the function is not defined inside the `SomeObject` class.